# Non-Kähler pseudo-Kähler manifolds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry

A *pseudo-Kähler manifold* is a complex manifold $(X, I)$ endowed with a non-degenerate closed $(1, 1)$-form $\omega$. In that case, the symmetric tensor $g(\cdot, \cdot) = \omega(\cdot, I \cdot)$ is a [pseudo-Riemannian metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_manifold).

> **Question.** What are examples of compact complex manifolds which are pseudo-Kähler but not Kähler?

Comment: Do you want (a) compact complex manifolds with a pseudo-Kähler metric which is not Kähler, or (b) compact complex manifolds which admit a pseudo-Kähler metric but *do not admit* a Kähler metric? (a) is easy, (b) is harder.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler (b)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that the easiest example of compact pseudo-Kähler manifold which does not admit any Kähler metric is the [Kodaira-Thurston manifold](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2041749?origin=crossref#metadata_info_tab_contents). See for instance the introduction of

*Yamada, Takumi*, [**Ricci flatness of certain compact pseudo-Kähler solvmanifolds**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.geomphys.2011.06.006), J. Geom. Phys. 62, No. 5, 1338-1345 (2012). [ZBL1239.53100](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1239.53100).

Answer (score 6):

Another collection of examples come via hyperbolic 4-manifolds. Since hyperbolic metrics are conformally flat, the twistor space $Z$ of an oriented hyperbolic 4-manifold is actually a complex manifold with complex structure $J$ (this is due to Atiyah-Hitchin-Singer, Self duality in 4-dimensional Riemannian geometry, https://www.jstor.org/stable/79638). There is also a natural closed 2-form $\omega$ on the twistor space. In the case of hyperbolic 4-manifolds, this pairs with $\omega$ to give a pseudo-Kähler metric. This is described for $H^4$ itself in a paper I wrote with Dmitri Panov (Section 2.3.2 of this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.3237.pdf). Now, the twistor space $Z$ of a 4-manifold $M$ has the same fundamental group as $M$. So when $M$ is a compact hyperbolic 4-manifold, $Z$ can't carry any Kähler structure whatsoever, by results on the structure of Kähler fundamental groups (I'm afraid I don't a know a reference off the top of my head here!).

Comment: A reference for the final statement is Theorem $6.22$ of *Fundamental Groups of Compact Kähler Manifolds* by Amorós, Burger, Corlette, Kotschick, & Toledo.